# Pure XAML approach to evenly distributing an unknown number of children in a container

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

Let's say I have a StackPanel (Orientation="Horizontal") with a fixed width and a **variable/unknown** amount of children, how do I tell all the children in XAML (not in code) to set their widths' to all be equal and fill up the entire StackPanel's width?

It's easy enough to do with Grid when you **know** the number of children (just use ColumnDefinitions with Width="*"), but I'm not sure how to do it with panels (StackPanel, PivotHeaderPanel, etc) or lists (GridView, ListView, etc).

Comment: I think you mean [Grid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.aspx) not [GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242705), correct?

Comment: So you want all the items in one row and divide the width equally?

Comment: Reworded the question...hopefully that helps. @JayZuo-MSFT, in essence yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, what you need is a panel like the UniformGrid in WPF. UniformGrid provides a way to arrange content in a grid where all the cells in the grid have the same size. However there is no build-in UniformGrid in UWP. We can implement it by ourselves or use a third party UniformGrid like what in [WinRTXamlToolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/UniformGrid/UniformGrid.cs).

Here using the UniformGrid in WinRTXamlToolkit for example. To use WinRTXamlToolkit, we can install it from nuget: [WinRT XAML Toolkit for Windows 10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit).

Then add `xmlns` in the page like:

```xaml
xmlns:toolkit="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"
```

After this, we can use the UniformGrid like:

```xaml
<toolkit:UniformGrid Rows="1" />
```

Here I set the `Rows` property to `1` and the `Columns` property to the default value `0`. A value of zero (0) for the Columns property specifies that the column count is computed based on the number of rows and the number of visible child elements that are in the Grid. So all the children in this UniformGrid will be put in one row and as this is a UniformGrid, all the columns will have the same width.

Following is a sample that uses UniformGrid as the `ItemsPanel` of a `GridView`:

XAML:

```xaml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <GridView x:Name="MyGridView" Height="60">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:UniformGrid Rows="1" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>

            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="Red">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" Text="{Binding }" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Add a item</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> myList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
    private int i = 6;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyGridView.ItemsSource = myList;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myList.Add(i.ToString());
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

And it looks like:
[image]