# c# programmatically add controls adjacently?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I do this in form load

```
    TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
    TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();

    this.Controls.Add(tb1);
    this.Controls.Add(tb2);
```

It puts one textbox over another (not vertically or horizontally, but covering each other), which is not what I want.

I could manually try to position them programmatically, but is there a way where I can have each control appear adjacently when I add them?

Comment: See my posting for adding buttons.  You need to set the left and top properties : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373302/how-to-create-dynamic-row-and-columns/37373407#37373407

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx).
Here a short example code that you can test using Linqpad

```
Form f = new Form();
FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
flp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
flp.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
f.Controls.Add(flp);
TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
flp.Controls.Add(t1);
TextBox t2 = new TextBox();
flp.Controls.Add(t2);
f.Show();
```

Comment: pretty good, so in terms of how much more code than it'd otherwise be, I see, within a form load,  it's 4 lines and then the other 4 lines  similar to what  I had(but adding to the flow layout panel)  . http://pastebin.com/raw/5qSc2pEK

Comment: @barlop you can just use it in the designer without code. There is also the `TableLayoutPanel`