# Add dynamic Buttons according to ListBox items

Tags: c#, winforms, button, dynamic-controls

I need to convert ListBox items into dynamic Buttons. Means, my tool has a ComboBox for showing text files in a folder which contain text links.
When items are selected in the ComboBox, the ListBox below is filled.
I want to remove the ComboBox and add Buttons instead.

How to add Buttons dynamically in a Panel, with variable `Text` and `Width`?
How to handle `Click` events of the dynamically Buttons?

This is how the software is currently working:

[image]

I'm want to change the interface as shown in the image.
At the moment, my concern is the dynamic Buttons functionality and how to add them to a Panel.
I need help with that.

This is what I need to do:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# programmatically add controls adjacently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510367/c-sharp-programmatically-add-controls-adjacently)

Comment: Flow layout panel. Or could use a datagridview with a link column(not the look you're going for though)

Comment: That layout is easily achieved using a FlowLayoutPanel, if the size of the Panel is constant. Otherwise, you can use a TableLayoutPanel, which allows flexible resizing of its child Controls. You can make a Control span more than one Column, if needed. -- The rounded Button, if you're not already using a third-party library, requires a Custom Control derived from Control. You can draw a GraphicsPath that defines the rounded section of a transparent Control.

Comment: I suggest you lay it out the way you want it in the designer first and then you'll have a complete list of what property values (e.g. font, margin, padding) to set on your controls when you create them dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys! It's done as I expected. I used GunaFramework for corner round buttons. And I used below code for dynamic buttons.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Button button = new Button();
                button.Tag = i;
                button.AutoSize = true;
                
                button.Text = fNames[i].Split('\\').Last().Replace(".txt", ""); 
                button.Click += (s, c) => { your action; }; 
                FlowLayOutPanel.Controls.Add(button);
            }
```

[image]